# Serial.availableForWrite versus Serial.flush

Tags: serial, arduino-due, softwareserial, serial-data, matlab

Is there a difference between the following two line codes?

> > while (Serial.availableForWrite <= 0) {}

versus

> > Serial.flush()

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```cpp
while (Serial.availableForWrite() <= 0) {}
```

waits until the serial output buffer is **not full**. Whereas

```cpp
Serial.flush();
```

waits until the serial output buffer is **empty**.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/availableforwrite/

> `availableForWrite` Get the number of bytes (characters) available for writing in the serial buffer without blocking the write operation

Write operations on Arduino streams wait if they can't write the data to output. You can use the count returned by `availableForWrite` to avoid this blocking.

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/flush/

> `flush` Waits for the transmission of outgoing serial data to complete.

One use of `flush()` is to wait until the data are sent away before putting the MCU into sleep mode.